# Conda install conflict with remaining packages

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, rdkit, plotnine

For some reason, I can't install any packages with my current setup. I have conda version 3.7 and python 3.4. I've tried the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge rdkit

conda install -c rdkit rdkit

conda install -c conda-forge plotnine
```

and in all three cases I just get `"Unsatisfiable package specifications."` and the hint it generates is `"rdkit has a conflict with the remaining packages."` or `"plotnine has a conflict with the remaining packages."`

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this?

Comment: Are you using any virtual environments? You can avoid a lot of conflicts by using dedicated virtual envs depending on what you're doing with your application.

Comment: No, I am not using a virtual environment. Perhaps I could? I don't have a lot of experience using them.

Comment: For anyone reading this thread, I updated my conda version to 4.2.23 and it now shows me that rdkit and python 3.4 are incompatible. So, I tried creating a virtual environment for python 2.7 and it's getting stuck at "Solving package specifications." I'm going to create a new thread for this.

Comment: Why not update conda all the way to the most recent version (4.5.x)?

Comment: @chemdatafarmer - https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: @darthbith I tried the conda update conda command and it only gave me 4.2.13

Comment: @ScottSkiles Thanks for the link